# file_get_html only working for certain URL (OVH issue?)

Tags: php, html

I am using simple_html_dom script to gather certain information from external pages.

The script I have been using worked pretty well until today. I tried to look for where the error came from and it seems the file_get_html function is not working anymore, only on certain URLs.

The basic code I am using is:

```
<?php include_once('../simple_html_dom.php'); 

echo file_get_html('http://www.hltv.org/match/2295100-')->plaintext; ?>
```

When executing this, I have a blank page on my OVH shared server. It seems the page returns a 503 error, even if the page actually exists. I am able to extract the content of the page from other servers (like AWS) however. What troubles me is that it's been working for 4 months now without any issue.

I made sure the MAX_FILE_SIZE of the simple_html_dom was increased but could not find any solution to this.

Any idea to solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: works fine on my end, maybe your IP is banned or something, try to `cURL` the contents first, then debug from there

Comment: HTTP error 503 indicates a temporary server inability to fulfil the request.

Comment: Do you have errors turned on? Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your scripts.

Comment: 'error_reporting(E_ALL);' did not show anything, the page is still blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php'); 
$result = file_get_html('http://www.hltv.org/match/2295100-');
echo $result->plaintext;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, though some versions of PHP don't allow you to chain `->` with a function call. If it is a shared server, the PHP version is probably older than it should be and thus does not allow this.

Comment: How do you know the questioner's PHP version?

Comment: Shared hosting = old PHP, typically.

Comment: Or he could have the latest version. Don't assume; if you need to know something you should use the comments area to ask for more information.

Comment: Since the code works fine for @Ghost, it means that it's related to the server's PHP environment. This would lead to a bad PHP version.

Comment: Same effect, page is still blank. I'm using PHP 5.6.6

Comment: even with the reporting error I have nothing. What is weird is that I can access other domain (like google.com), but not this page.